# string or binary data would be truncated. when large string is inserted in a field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

in my model in asp.net mvc5 website there is field name

```
   [Display(Name = "Detail (A-Z)")]
            [StringLength(int.MaxValue)]
            [AllowHtml]
            public string Description { get; set; }
```

i want to have maximum string size for this field . i used `StringLength(int.Maxvalue)` 
when i enter large string(not very large) it gives error .on small string it works fine.
i changed the removed the stringlength data annotation but still gives the same error.i think stringlangth should allow maximum characters.

Comment: Please check the Description Column length database.

Comment: please anyone help me so that i can enter whole html page (or MS word formated page) into this field?

Comment: @FiazAhmed check the answer posted bellow.

Comment: Remove `[StringLength(int.MaxValue)]` attribute

Comment: @FiazAhmed Are you using Code First approach ? If yes, please perform the migration. If you are using database first approach simply update the database column length for this attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the problem with the Server side code. The issue is with the database's field's length. You are sending longer string than the DB column can hold. Thus the error is raised for longer strings.

Do the followings:
`[StringLength(X)]` here x is the length of the column in the DB.

If you want the input to be max in length which is required in case of html inputs, then remove the `StringLength` property from the model. Which would not restrict the input length. And then change the DB column to be `Varchar (Max)`.

Comment: sir thanks for helping. yes i want to enter maximum size input. i tried to remove the stringlength property from the model but still the error occurs.please any workarround.

Comment: Only removing the length from the model will not work. You need to alter the size of the column in the database as stated above. What is the type/length of the column in the database which will store the input (Description)?

Comment: Thanks Rahatur the Description filed was nvarchar(255) now i changed to nvarchar(MAX) do i need to remove stringlength annotation from model also?

Comment: @FiazAhmed Yes, you can remove the string length. If the answer worked for you hope you don't mind marking the answer as accepted and vote up?